# How to make duplicates of unique datastore entity in google data store?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to enforce unique of a class in google data store. Here is how I enforce the uniqueness

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import Unique


class UserTag(ndb.Model)):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', required=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        super(UserTag, self)._pre_put_hook()
        success = Unique.create(self.user_key)
        if not success:
            raise Exception('Cannot create unique key: %s' % unique_key)
```

This works fine until I want to keep a version of `UserTag` in `archive` namespace whenever an instance of `UserTag` is modified.

```
cloned_user_tag = UserTag(user_key=orig.user_key, name=orig.name, namespace='archive')
cloned_user_tag.put(cloned_user_tag)  # throw exception
```

Then an exception will be thrown

```
Exception: Cannot create unique key: UserTag:123
```

What is the best way to avoid this problem? What is the best way to temporarily suspend uniqueness enforcement? Maybe I can skip the `Unique.create` if the namespace is `archive`, but

1) how can I know the current namespace

2) is there a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can check the namespace inside `_pre_put_hook()` like this:

```
    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        super(UserTag, self)._pre_put_hook()        
        if self._key.namespace() != 'archive':
            success = Unique.create(self.user_key)
            if not success:
                raise Exception('Cannot create unique key: %s' % unique_key)
```